# Is there a way to create in wix empty page like when using visual studio code and live server and the page it's opening on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, velo

When using visual studio code and then opening with live server the index.html the site in the web browser is looking like this:

[image: page with visual studio code and live server]

on my wix site it looks like this:

[image: wix site page]

on the right there is a scroll bar and if I drag the scroll bar up down I will see my site menu on the top above the map.

but I want in my wix site to have the page the same as it is in the live server.

this is my code in both visual studio code html file and in the wix html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
  
<style>#map
    {
        width: 1500px;
        height:900px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    
    #map.fullscreen {
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
      }</style>

<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"
      defer
    ></script>

<script>let map;

    function initMap() {
        // The location of Uluru
        const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };
    
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: uluru,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          options: {
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
        });
    
        /*const myLatlng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
        // Create the initial InfoWindow.
      let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Click the map to get Lat/Lng!",
        position: myLatlng,
      });
    
      infoWindow.open(map);
      // Configure the click listener.
      map.addListener("mousemove", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
        // Close the current InfoWindow.
        infoWindow.close();
        // Create a new InfoWindow.
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
        });
        infoWindow.setContent(
          JSON.stringify(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON(), null, 2)
        );
        infoWindow.open(map);
      });*/
    
        // Create the DIV to hold the control.
      const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
      // Create the control.
      const centerControl = createCenterControl(map);
      // Append the control to the DIV.
      centerControlDiv.appendChild(centerControl);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);
    
        const chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };
    
        /**
         * Creates a control that recenters the map on Chicago.
         */
        function createCenterControl(map) {
          const controlButton = document.createElement("button");
        
          // Set CSS for the control.
          controlButton.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
          controlButton.style.border = "2px solid #fff";
          controlButton.style.borderRadius = "3px";
          controlButton.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
          controlButton.style.color = "rgb(25,25,25)";
          controlButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
          controlButton.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
          controlButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
          controlButton.style.lineHeight = "28px";
          controlButton.style.borderLeftWidth = "8px";
          controlButton.style.margin = "8px 8px 22px 0";
          controlButton.style.padding = "0 5px";
          controlButton.style.textAlign = "center";
          controlButton.textContent = "Center Map";
          controlButton.title = "Click to recenter the map";
          controlButton.type = "button";
          
          // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
          controlButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            map.setCenter(chicago);
          });
          return controlButton;
        }
    
        const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
            bounds: {
                north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
                south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
                west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
                east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
            },
          });
    }
    
      window.initMap = initMap;</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't want this menu and controls and stuff in my wix page. just only the map like in the live server screenshot:

[image: wix menus in page]

Comment: I managed to do it :)